# Extra characters when script is run as local system

Tags: powershell, registry

I have a script with a couple of functions. The first function creates some registry keys in HKLM\Software\Test (\UDF1-30). The second function takes any strings written in the UDF# keys, contatinates them (one line per UDF, seperated by the pipe character) and copies them to HKLM\Software\CentraStage\Custom#.

For testing, I threw the following string into UDF12:

```
PatchSched:{"StartTime":"23:00:00","TzBias":-480,"Duration":240,"DayOfYear":[],"DayOfWeek":[-2],"Days":[],"MonthlyDayOfWeek":[6],"Months":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12],"Ordering":[4],"ScheduleType":7}
```

When I run the script as the local administrator, I get that same string into Custom12. But, when I run the script as the Local System, I get random pipes in the string:

```
PatchSched:{"StartTime":"23:00:00","TzBias":-480,"Duration":240,"DayOfYear":[],"DayOfWeek":[-2],"Days":[],"MonthlyD|ayOfWeek":[6],"Months":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12],"Ordering":[4],"ScheduleType":7}
```

Why in the world, would this happen? Here is the script:

```
Function Add-UserDefinedFields {
    <#
        .DESCRIPTION
            This function checks if HKLM\SOFTWARE\Test exists. If not, it creates the required registry structure, to support Update-UserDefinedFields.
    #>

    Set-Location HKLM:

    If (-Not(Test-Path .\Software\Test\UDF29)) {
        # If the Test registry key does not exist...
        # Create the Test registry key.
        New-Item -Path .\Software -Name Test

        # Create 30 UDF registry keys.
        For ($i = 1; $i -le 30; $i++) {
            New-Item -Path .\Software\Test -Name UDF$i
        }
    }
}

Function Update-UserDefinedFields {
    <#
        .DESCRIPTION
            This function reads the value of each UDF registry entry, in HKLM\SOFTWARE\Test and writes the value(s) to the corresponding UDF in HKLM\SOFTWARE\CentraStage.
    #>

    Set-Location HKLM:

    For ($i = 1; $i -le 30; $i++) {
        # For each of the 30 UDF registry keys...

        # Initialize variable.
        $udfValue = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.List[string]"

        Get-ItemProperty .\SOFTWARE\Test\UDF$i -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Out-String -Stream | Where-Object { $_ -NOTMATCH '^ps.+' } | ForEach-Object {
            $udfValue.Add($_)
        }

        $udfString = $udfValue -join '|'

        $udfString = $udfString.Replace(' ', '')
        While ($udfString -like "*||*") {
            $udfString = $udfString.replace('||', '|')
        }

        If ($udfString) {
            # Trim the leading and trailing characters (|).
            $udfString = $udfString.substring(1, $udfString.length - 2)
        }

        Write-Host ("Writing to UDF{0}: {1}" -f $i, $udfString)

        # For each Test UDF, write the concatinated value to the corresponding AEM UDF registry location.
        $null = New-ItemProperty -Path .\SOFTWARE\CentraStage -Name Custom$i -PropertyType String -Value $udfstring -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    }
}

Add-UserDefinedFields
Update-UserDefinedFields
```

Comment: Add a bunch of temporary ```write-host $udfString``` lines after changing its value and try to isolate the specific line where it's not doing what you expect (or at least where it's doing it differently as LocalSystem). that might help diagnose the underlying difference.

Comment: Also, see if you can reproduce the issue with a hard-coded array of strings rather than reading the registry, and post that here as well - it'll be easier for other people to investigate the issue if they can cut & paste directly into a powershell session.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured it out. The code now looks like this:

```
    Function Add-TestUserDefinedFields {
    <#
        .DESCRIPTION
            This function checks if HKLM\SOFTWARE\Test exists. If not, it creates the required registry structure, to support Update-UserDefinedFields.
    #>

    Set-Location HKLM:

    If (-Not(Test-Path .\Software\Test\UDF29)) {
        # If the Test registry key does not exist...
        # Create the Test registry key.
        New-Item -Path .\Software -Name Test

        # Create 30 UDF registry keys.
        For ($i = 1; $i -le 30; $i++) {
            New-Item -Path .\Software\Test -Name UDF$i
        }
    }
}

Function Update-UserDefinedFields {
    <#
        .DESCRIPTION
            This function reads the value of each UDF registry entry, in HKLM\SOFTWARE\Test and writes the value(s) to the corresponding UDF in HKLM\SOFTWARE\CentraStage.
    #>

    Set-Location HKLM:

    For ($i = 1; $i -le 30; $i++) {
        # For each of the 30 UDF registry keys...

        # Initialize variable.
        $udfValue = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.List[string]"

        (Get-ItemProperty .\SOFTWARE\Test\UDF$i -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).PSObject.Properties | Where-Object { $_.Name -NOTMATCH '^ps.+' } | ForEach-Object {
            $udfValue.Add("$($_.Name):$($_.Value)")
        }

        $udfString = $udfValue -join '|'

        Write-Output ("The value of `$udfString is {0}" -f $udfString) | out-file C:\Synoptek\test.txt -Append

        $udfString = $udfString.Replace(' ', '')
        While ($udfString -like "*||*") {
            $udfString = $udfString.replace('||', '|')
        }

        Write-Output ("Writing to UDF{0}: {1}" -f $i, $udfString)

        # For each Test UDF, write the concatinated value to the corresponding  UDF registry location.
        $null = New-ItemProperty -Path .\SOFTWARE\CentraStage -Name Custom$i -PropertyType String -Value $udfstring -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    }
}

Add-TestUserDefinedFields
Update-UserDefinedFields
```